# how to assign several different type variable in one vector or distinguish its type

Tags: c++, vector, types

i have two different dataset like below in worldGiving.txt and OrganDonor.txt

```
    in worldGiving.txt 
    Australia   60% 76% 2   37% 12  67% 10
    Ireland 60% 79% 1   34% 15  66% 13
    Canada  58% 64% 10  42% 7   67% 10
    New Zealand 57% 66% 8   38% 11  68% 9
    United States   57% 57% 13  42% 7   71% 3
    Netherlands 53% 73% 3   34% 15  51% 49
    Indonesia   52% 71% 5   41% 10  43% 77
    United Kingdom  51% 72% 4   26% 35  56% 33
    Paraguay    50% 48% 23  42% 7   61% 22
    Denmark 49% 70% 7   23% 45  54% 43
    Liberia 49% 12% 109 53% 2   81% 1
    Iran    48% 51% 21  24% 41  70% 6
    Turkmenistan    48% 30% 52  58% 1   56% 33
    Qatar   47% 53% 17  17% 67  71% 3
    Sri Lanka   47% 42% 30  43% 6   55% 38
    Trinidad and Tobago 45% 44% 26  30% 23  62% 19
    Finland 45% 50% 22  27% 30  57% 29
    Philippines 45% 32% 47  44% 5   58% 26
    Hong Kong   44% 64% 10  13% 87  56% 33
    Oman    44% 39% 32  22% 48  72% 2
    Cyprus  44% 56% 14  27% 30  48% 57
    ...

in organDonor.txt
Croatia 36,5
Spain   35,1
Belgium 32,9
Malta   30
Puerto Rico 26,3
USA 25,6
France  24,9
Estonia 24,3
Portugal    24
Norway  23,5
Slovenia    23
Austria 22,5
Italy   22,4
Finland 19,9
Czech Rep.  19,8
Lativa  19
UK  18,3
Ireland 17
Uruguay 16,5
Poland  16,1
Argentina   15,7
Australia   15,6
Netherlands 15,1
Sweden  15
Canada  14,7
Hungary 14,3
Lithuania   13,7
Denmark 13,4
Slovak Rep. 13,1
...
```

and below is my code.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string line;
vector<vector<string>> extractingData;
vector<vector<string>> extractingData2;

string pathExtract;
string pathStorage;
string pathMerged;

fstream extractingFile;
fstream extractingFile2;

void mergeData(vector<vector<string>> extractingData, vector<vector<string>> extractingData2, string pathStorage);

vector<vector<string>> ReadData(fstream& extractingFile, vector<vector<string>> extractingData, string pathExtract)
{
    extractingFile.open(pathExtract);

    int i = 0;
    int index;
    if (extractingFile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(extractingFile, line))
        {
            istringstream iss(line);
            extractingData.resize(i + 1);
            int j = 0;
            while (!iss.eof()){
                extractingData[i].resize(j+1);
                iss >> extractingData[i][j];
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return extractingData;
    }
}


int main() {
    pathExtract = "worldGiving.txt";
    pathStorage = "OrganDonors.txt";
    pathMerged = "merged.txt";
    extractingData=ReadData(extractingFile, extractingData, pathStorage);
    extractingData2=ReadData(extractingFile2, extractingData2, pathExtract);
    mergeData(extractingData, extractingData2, pathMerged);

}


void mergeData(vector<vector<string>> extractingData, vector<vector<string>> extractingData2, string pathStorage){

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i<extractingData2.size() && i<extractingData.size())
    {
        cout << extractingData[i][0];
        while (extractingData[i][0] != extractingData2[j][0] && j != extractingData2.size()-1)
        {
            j++;
        }
        if (extractingData[i][0] == extractingData2[j][0])
        {
            for (std::vector<string>::iterator it = extractingData2[j].begin()+1; it != extractingData2[j].end(); ++it)
            {
                /*auto back = std::move(extractingData2[j].back);
                extractingData[i].push_back(std::move(back));*/
                auto back = *it;
                extractingData[i].push_back(back);
            }

        }   
        i++;
        j = 0;
    }


        i = 0;
        ofstream outFile(pathStorage);
        while (i<extractingData2.size() && i<extractingData.size())
        {
            for (std::vector<string>::iterator it = extractingData[i].begin(); it != extractingData[i].end(); ++it) {
                outFile << *it <<' ';
            }
            outFile << endl;
            i++;
        }   
    }
```

but I met a problem that more than one term named countries like "New Zealand" and "United states" assign seperately in more than one block like "New", "Zealand".
so i can't compare two text files appropriately. so i think if i could distinguish its type which is numerical or not when assign it to Vector, i can solve this problem. 
how can i do?

Comment: you can modify your file format. use other sign (ex #) instead of space for separator. so as `New Zealand#57%#66%#8#38%#11#68%#9`

Comment: unfortunately, there are more than one text files i should merge in. so i can't do that all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot change you format to more clearly delimit country names, you could count how many items you find and assign them starting form the end. what remains after you have found your values should be joined into the name.

Comment: oh i see. if there are some irregular length array, i can sense it is several terms named countries. thank you.